# How to create a hash of all possible combinations in SQL or Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a simple query:

```
select key, name from cities
```

Which gives me values like so:

```
11 | Chicago
21 | New York
31 | Boston
```

What I need to be able to do is to create a hash of all possible combinations either in SQL or in Java in order to receive this result at the end:

```
11 | Chicago
21 | New York
31 | Boston
32 | Chicago/New York
42 | Chicago/Boston
52 | New York/Boston
63 | Chicago/New York/Boston
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does your expected output not have a row with all three cities?  What if the sum of the key values is not unique?

Comment: You're right I just added that last result with three cities. The keys will be always unique I know that.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a hash"? The term "hash" has multiple meanings (I blame Perl) depending on the context, which is not exactly clear here...

Comment: Sorry, I guess hash is not the correct description. It's more like a Map right where 11, 21, etc are the keys and city names are values.

Comment: Why is Chicago/NewYork 33 and not 32?  What happens in the general case when two combinations add up to the same key? A Java Hash cannot hold duplicate keys.

Comment: What if there 100 cities instead of 3? What would your keys look like then? Do the hash values even need to be human readable?

Comment: Let say that I know that the number of cities will never be greater then lets say 15. The uniqueness of the keys are not my main concern right now because the values I really using are much greater and so this is just an example. And yes the Chicago/NewYork should be 32 I just corrected that...

Comment: So, you are just looking for a way to produce all combinations in a set?

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but could be a start:

first I created a function:

```
create or replace function sum_string(str in varchar2) return number is
  Result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select ' || str || ' from dual'
    into result;
  return(Result);
end sum_string;
/
```

then comes the query (`your_table` is your table)

```
with jwt as  (
  select t1.key k1, t1.name n1, t2.key k2, t2.name n2, t1.key + t2.key jkey
    from your_table t1
    left outer join (select key, name
                       from your_table
                     union all
                     select 0 "key", null "name" from dual) t2 on t1.key <>
                                                                  t2.key
  )
select jkey, max(aaa.pth)
  from (select sys_connect_by_path(t.n1, '/') pth,
               sum_string(ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(t.k1, '+'), '+')) jkey
          from jwt t
         start with t.k2 = 0
        connect by nocycle prior k1 = k2) aaa
 group by jkey;
```